# Android texture mapping - incorrect mapping with a PNG file

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, texture-mapping, uv-mapping

I'm no expert when it comes to opengles but I have been using it for a lot of my applications. I created a new app to refresh myself on opengles and I got a square to draw. Now I applied texture mapping and it was mapping incorrectly. I checked the UV coords thoroughly over and over again and it seemed right. After hours of confusion I finally decided to change the .png to something random again that I downloaded from the web. Voila! It was mapping correctly. When I switched back to the old .png it mapped incorrectly again. Can someone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Going to need some screenshots and the two PNGs.

Comment: I don't have the old png file anymore but I could always go grab it again. These two were off the web. The first one was from a german android game dev tutorial site and I just right clicked and downloaded. The second one was from a photobucket like site where you can "actually" download the file.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its about image size. Maybe your png dimensions are not a multiple of 2.
Regards